# What's the probability that the multiplication of $t$ elements (repeats allowed) from the list $x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n$ is less than 1?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Suppose I have a list of numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_n$, and suppose I pick $t$ elements (with repeats allowed) from that list, and multiply those numbers together. What is the probability that the multiplication is less than 1?

For example, if my list was $[0.3, 1.4]$ and I wanted to multiply 3 elements from this list (with repeats), the possible results would be

$\\0.3*0.3*0.3\\0.3*0.3*1.4\\0.3*1.4*0.3\\0.3*1.4*1.4\\1.4*0.3*0.3\\1.4*0.3*1.4\\1.4*1.4*0.3\\1.4*1.4*1.4$

And the probability of picking a term less than $1$ would be $7/8$ since the only term greater than $1$ is the last term.

The least efficient method would be to compute every possible multiplication of t elements from that list, which is a total of $n^t$ possible strings of $t$ elements, each string requiring $t-1$ multiplications. Is there a faster way of doing this? I have to do this sort of math using R with a list of up to 1500 elements and I have to pick up to 250 elements from that list (with repeats), and I want to do that without some serious nested for loops.

Comment: You can probably get an approximate answer using central limit theorem. Are you interested?

Comment: Yes I would like to see how to approximate if possible.

Comment: I'm going to look into whether the results of each string are close to normal when n is large.

Comment: Yes exactly, product of t numbers would be less than one if sum of their logarithms is less than zero. Thus find the mean and standard deviation or the distribution generated by the logarithms of these numbers and apply central limit theorem to that to find the area of the normal distribution to the left of zero.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!!

Comment: What if one of the numbers $x_i$ is 0? I'm trying to take the log of every number in my list, but that's becoming pretty impossible...

Comment: If any one of the numbers in the product is equal to zero, then the entire product term is equal to zero. Thus, the probability that the product of the terms is less than one is equal to the probability that at least one of the terms is equal to zero plus the probability that none of the terms are zero times the probability that the sum of the logarithms of rest of the terms is less than zero.